# Can't access results of arrayfun when UniformOutput is false

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm trying to use nchoosek in order to apply it to n arrays, n being the input of the user

```
function returnit = nchoosek2(array_length)
    f = @(x) nchoosek(1:1:(array_length+1),x);
    t = 1:(array_length);
    returnit = arrayfun(@(x)f(x),t,'UniformOutput',0);
end
```

It doesn't return error, but when I try it, i get an array containing n arrays

```
>> nchoosek2(5)

ans = 

[15x2 double]    [20x3 double]    [15x4 double]    [6x5 double]
```

The issue is that I can't manage to access the values INSIDE of those arrays. I searched in the MatLab's documentation, this case is described without giving a clue about how to access those values. I only know that this kind of results is given because the size of the arrays is not the same for each.

Do you have any idea how to access those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of your function is a cell array, so you need to access data inside using curly braces {}. Check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html?refresh=true) for more info about that.

Simple example with an `array_length` of 3:

```
A = nchoosek2(3)

A = 

    [4x1 double]    [6x2 double]    [4x3 double]
```

If we use `celldisp` to display the content of the cell array:

```
celldisp(A)

A{1} =

     1
     2
     3
     4



A{2} =

     1     2
     1     3
     1     4
     2     3
     2     4
     3     4



A{3} =

     1     2     3
     1     2     4
     1     3     4
     2     3     4
```

Yay! So you can access the content each cell from `A` using `{}` or the cells themselves using regular brackets `()`.

Is that what you meant?

Comment: That's actually exactly what I meant! didn't know neither about celldisp nor the bracket, thanks.

Comment: Awesome you're welcome! That would be great if you could mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the green checkmark beside it. Thanks!